# Mapping space from a quotient space

Tags: gn.general-topology

For $X/{\sim}$ a quotient space, 
$$
Map(X/{\sim},Y)\subset Map(X,Y).
$$
But is this inclusion always a homeomorphism on its image? (Assuming compact-open topology on the mapping spaces.) If not what would be the most general setting to make it true? We can also assume that $X$ and $Y$ are compactly generated.

A related question: if $q\colon X\to X/{\sim}$ is a quotient map and $X/{\sim}$ is compact, does always exist a compact $Y\subset X$ such that $q(Y)=X/{\sim}$.

Comment: The second related question has negative answer: just consider the subspace $X=\{(x,y)\in [0,1]\times\mathbb R:x=0$ or $xy=1\}$ of the plane and let $q:X\to [0,1]$ we the projection onto the first coordinate. This map is quotient, but not compact-covering.

Comment: My previous "counterexample" is incorrect. The converse in true. Namely, the second related question has affirmative answer if $X$ is sequential and $X/\sim$ is a convergent sequence, see Lemma 3.5 in [S.Lin, P.Yan, Sequence-covering maps  of metric spaces, Topology Appl. 109 (2001) 301-314].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second question has negative answer: just consider the unit interval $[0,1]$ and let $\mathcal S$ be the family of all closed subsets with a unique non-isolated point in $[0,1]$. The family $\mathcal S$ is endowed with the discrete topology. Let $X=\{(x,S):x\in S\in\mathcal S\}\subset [0,1]\times\mathcal S$ be the topological sum of the family $\mathcal S$ and $q:X\to[0,1]$, $q:(x,S)\mapsto x$, be the natural projection. It is easy to see that the map $q$ is quotient but $q(K)\ne [0,1]$ for any compact subset $K\subset X$. So, the space $X$ is the topological sum of all convergent sequences in $[0,1]$. It is a locally compact locally countable space of density continuum.

It seems that the (metrizable locally compact locally countable) space $X$ and the equivalence relation $\sim=\{(x,y)\in X\times X:q(x)=q(y)\}$ yield also a counterexample to the first question for $Y=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Typo? Do you mean $\dots\subset [0;1]\times\mathcal S\ $ ?

Comment: Isn't your $X$ discrete?

Comment: Would you go into more details, please?

Comment: @Wlod-AA My $X$ is the topological sum of all convergent sequences in $[0,1]$, so is not discrete. The map $q$ is quotient because for any non-closed subset $F\subset [0,1]$ there exists a convergent sequence $S\subset [0,1]$ such that $S\cap F$ is not closed in $S$ and then $q^{-1}(F)$ is not closed in $X$.

Comment: The counterexample would produce a situation when the canonical injection$$\operatorname{Cont}([0,1],Y)\to\operatorname{Cont}(\alpha N,Y)^{\operatorname{Cont}(\alpha N,[0,1])}$$is not a homeomorphic embedding. My problem is that I have no idea what topology sits on $\operatorname{Cont}([0,1],Y)$. For a general $Y$ there is no single decent topology there I believe.

Comment: Taras, your example is very nice--purely conceptual, very clean.

Answer (score 3):

> @Victor has pointed out to my error in the **pre**-edited version--thank you, Victor. Now everything **IS** under control and **FIXED**.

Here, after @TarasBanakh, there is another example of a quotient map
$\ q: X\rightarrow X/{\sim} $ such that $X$ is compact but there is no compact subset $Y\subseteq X$ such that $f(Y)=f(X)$.

Let $Q\subset\mathbb R$ be the set of all rational numbers.
Let $\ J:=[0;1]:=\{x\in\mathbb R: 0\le x\le 1\},\ $ Define

$$ X\ :=\ \{(x\ y)\in J^2\,:\, |\{x\ y\}\cap Q| = 1\} $$

And let $\ p:X\rightarrow J\ $ be the projection $\ p(x\ y)\ := x.\ $
Then $p$ is onto, and for every $A\subseteq J$ we have:

1. $p^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$ when $A$ is open in $J$ because $p$ is induced by the Cartesian projection;
2. $p^{-1}(A)$ is not open in $X$ when $A$ is not open in $J$ because
   $p^{-1}(x)$ is dense in $\ \{x\}\times J\ $ for every $\ x\in J.\ $

Thus, $\ p\ $ is topologically equivalent to the respective quotient map.

> More than this, $p$ is an open map. Indeed, sets
>
> $$ B_{abcd}\ :=\ ((a;b)\times(c;d))\,\cap\, X$$
>
> form a topological base of $X$, and $\ p(B_{abcd}) = (a;b)\cap J.\ $ Thus $p$ is an open map.

Let $\ Y\subseteq X\ $ be a compact subset such that $\ p(Y)=[0;1]\ $ (a proof by contradiction). Then $\ Y\ $ is a countable union of its compact subsets $\ C_a:=(\{a\}\times\mathbb R)\cap Y\ $ and $\ D_a:=(\mathbb R\times\{a\})\cap Y,\ $ where $\ a\ $ runs over rational numbers. Then
sets $\ p(C_a)\ $ and $\ p(D_a)\ $ are compact and they cover $\ [0;1].\ $
Thus, by Baire's theorem one of these projections must have a non-empty interior in $\ [0;1]\ $ -- a contradiction. Thus such $\ Y\ $ does not exist.

Comment: By the way, open maps between completely metrizable spaces are compact-covering (this follows from the 0-dimensional Michael Selection Theorem). So, the space $X$ in the example of @Wlod-AA is not (and cannot be) complete (unlike to the topological sum of all convergent sequences which is completely metrizable).

Comment: My example has its modest advantage, it is metric separable (i.e. a kind of small).

Comment: and the map is open, not just quotient!

Comment: What happens with the sets $\{(t,0):\, t\in J\}$ and $\{(0,t):\, t\in J\}$? Are they in $X$? If yes, their union is the required $Y$. Or, perhaps, you meant $\{x,y\}$ not $\{xy\}$ in your formula?

Comment: @Victor, they are not in $X$. (BTW, simply the horizontal line would be enough, but it's not in $X$).

Comment: BTW, I had a trivial but nasty typo, now fixed.

Comment: I am sorry, I still didn't get your example. I think it still has another typo: $\{x,y\}\cap Q=1$, not the product of $x$ and $y$? Also, please check your formula for Y proving that it is a countable union of finite sets - it does not seem right. Also irrational numbers contain uncountable compact sets, take for example a complement to a union of neighborhoods over every rational. This union can be of any small measure as possible.

Comment: It's not a typo. When I mean a multiplication than I say so: $\cdot\ $ (I write "cdot"). Most of the time I simply treat a blank space as a separator, there is no need of any "," most of the time. To me unnecessary commas "," are a nuisance, are eyesores. (Please, let me write this way).

Comment: By the way, absolute value stands here for cardinality (as is common in set theory, e.g. $|\mathbb Z| = \aleph_0$.

Comment: But isn't the right-hand side of your big union formula just $X$ itself?

Comment: (Formally), you WERE right. It was another nasty typo. Now it's FIXED -- now it's $Y$ (twice, on the right hand side).

A good pedagogical computer should give me a tutorial in avoiding typos.

Comment: But why $(\{a\}\times \mathbb{R}) \cap Y$ is finite? As I said earlier irrational numbers contain even uncountable compacts.

Comment: @Victor, you are right, I have a HOLE in my proof, you've pointed to it (if $X$ were wrong too then it would be an ERROR). Thank you very much, and for your patience. I'll edit and keep for a moment my "answer" under construction. I feel that there is a 50-50 chance that my $X$ is correct. But if not, than after a couple of days I will remove my "answer" completely. Thank you again.

Comment: It looks like the example is good, otherwise Taras would not accept it :) In case you won't succeed to prove, please keep it as an open question. It's an interesting example.

Comment: I have fixed my $X$ already. Give me a couple minutes extra for LaTeX.

Comment: Good job! A very nice example and an elegant proof!

Comment: @Victor, thank you for your patience and understanding.